# Visual Studio checkin

Tags: sql-server-express, checkin

Hello everyone I am trying TFS 2012 express on my home server (just to try) and everything is fine.

Source control on my c# solution works! However, I am unsure where the source code repository of my solution resides for TFS 2012 express?

Does a "Check in file" from the solution save "ONLY" on the Sql express database?

Can you please explain to me and suggest a good site for documentation relating to TFS 2012 express.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 Express stores your source control repository in a SQL Express database, which is installed locally during setup.

You can also sign up for [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/) which hosts your source control in the cloud. It is free just like the express desktop edition for up to 5 team members.

Here are several links you can use to learn more about TFS 2012:

1. [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express#product-express-tfs)
2. [MSDN Team Foundation Server2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx)